# How to add query fields to Map?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to add **QueueId** information from soql query and trying to put into another Map - groupDetailQueueIds.

```
Map<Id, QueueSobject> groupDetailQueueIds = new Map<Id, QueueSobject>();

Map<Id, QueueSobject> groupDetail = new Map<Id, QueueSobject>([SELECT Id, SobjectType, QueueId, Queue.Name FROM QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType = 'Case']);

for(Map<Id, QueueSobject> queidsMap : groupDetail){
    groupDetailQueueIds.put(queidsMap, groupDetail.QueueId);
}
```

from the above query only *QueueId* field information I'm trying to put in another Map 'groupDetailQueueIds'. Any help?

Error message : getting an error called -

> Variable does not exist: QueueId

at this line - `groupDetailQueueIds.put(queidsMap, groupDetail.QueueId);`

Comment: You should stop putting 4 spaces at the start of all of your lines. Stackexchange sites like this one use _Markdown_ for formatting text, and starting each line with 4 spaces turns your text into a code block. Having your entire question be a "code block" makes it harder to read. Please read through [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to get a better idea of how to format your questions.

Comment: You also don't need to include a "sign-off" (i.e. "Regards, Basha") here. Your username appears just below your question on the right-hand side.

Comment: @DerekF, Sure Thanks for the details . Next time I will follow these instructions. Any help on question please.

Comment: Also, if you're getting an error message, it's important that you include the error message (in its entirety, without making any changes).

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is incorrect here on at least 2 levels.

I'm kinda surprised that `for(Map<Id, QueueSobject> queidsMap : groupDetail){` isn't giving you an error (I get an error when trying to reproduce this via anonymous apex).

The syntax for the variation of `for` that you're using here looks like

```
for(<loop variable type> <loop variable name> : <something that implements iterable>)
```

If you're iterating over a map, the `<something that implements iterable>` is going to either be the *keyset* of the map, or the *values* of the map.
*It is not going to be just the map itself, as your code is trying to do*.

e.g.

```
// The type of this map's key is "String"
// The type of this map's values is "Integer"
Map<String, Integer> integersByName = new Map<String, Integer>{
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3
};

// The loop variable type needs to be the same as the type of the thing you're looping over
// In this case, we're iterating over the keyset, which is of type String
for(String mapKey :integersByName.keyset()) {
    system.debug(mapKey); // will print "one", "two", and "three"
}

// In this case, we're iterating over the values, which is of type Integer
for(Integer mapValue :integersByName.values()) {
    system.debug(mapValue); // will print "1", "2", and "3"
}
```

In my example, while you can access `integersByName` inside of the loop, you generally won't be doing that.
In your provided code, `groupDetail.QueueId` is wrong because `groupDetail` is a Map, and Maps don't have a `QueueId` property. It seems like you were trying to treat `groupDetail` as an instance of a single thing from inside your map, but the way you tried to do it is incorrect.

If you had set up your loop variable correctly, *that* would be the instance of a single thing from your map (that you could then use to extract data from).

While you can correct your code, I have a suggestion to improve it.
You see, your `groupDetail` Map isn't really doing anything for you. It's just making it harder to loop over and get at the information that you want.

Instead of putting the result of the query into a Map, you should instead either store the result of the query in a `List<QueueSObject>`, or just use a *[SOQL for loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm)* (where the query is part of the `for()` itself)

e.g.

```java
Map<Id, String> accountNameById = new Map<Id, String>();

// This is a "SOQL for loop"
// The query is part of the for(), while crucially not being inside of the body
//   of the for()
//   (because queries inside of loops is almost universally bad)
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 100]) {

    // Inside the body of the loop, you use the loop variable to access data from
    //   a single Account from the query.
    // This loop body will be executed once for each Account returned by the query
    //   and the loop variable is automatically updated to hold the next Account
    //   after we reach the end of the code inside the loop body.
    accountNameById.put(acct.Id, acct.Name);
}
```